# Bootstrap alert not working when used with ajax functionality

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm tyring to validate form via ajax, now I've used bootstrap's `alert alert-danger` and `alert alert-success` classes to give the `ui`, but when returned, it just renders as plain html without desired ui, what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#url').keyup(function(){
            var val = $('#url').val();
            $.post(
                '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/validator/check_for_url',
                {ajax:1,url:val},
                function(data){
                    $('#url_feedback').html(data);
                }
            );
        });
// php backend call via ajax
function check_for_url()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 1)
        {
            $url = $_POST['url'];
            if(!preg_match('%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i', $url))
            {
                echo '<p style="alert alert-danger">Invalid URL, make sure it\'s like http:// or https://</p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('user_url'=>$url));
                if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    echo '<p style="alert alert-danger">URL Address already exists...</p>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<p style="alert alert-success">URL address can be used...</p>';
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Define plain html...i made a test and you should change style for class....like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sDefL/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the dataType setting in the jQuery.ajax() documentation.

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

My guess is that your HTTP server for some reason does not return the correct MIME type and therefore jQuery might fall back to treating it as a regular string.